# CAN BUS Termination resistor sizing

Tags: serial, can, termination

I am using ISO1042 CAN Transceiver to establish communication between my board micro-controller with other board controller separated by 0.5m distance. I am using standard 120 ohm termination resistance. I would like to size the resistor.  For that I would like to estimate worst case power dissipation for the resistor. How can I do that?

Vcc1 of ISO1042 is 3.3V and Vcc2 is 5V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differential output voltage specification (in section 6.10 of the datasheet) says that the driver can generate a voltage drop of at most 3 V over the two termination resistors (2× 120 Ω in parallel). So the theoretical worst-case power dissipation in a single resistor during normal operation is (3 V)² / 120 Ω = 75 mW.

If you want to survive shorting the bus line(s) to some other voltage, you might need more.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the bus is shorted to lets say 5V or 10V, could you please tell me how can i calculate the power dissipation of the termination resistor ?

Comment: You have to know the voltages at both ends of the resistor.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: P = (V2 − V1)² / R

Comment: Hi, In the datasheet its mentioned like the short circuit current is limited to 100mA by the transceiver IC. so in that case can i use P = I2*R = 0.1*0.1*120 to size the resistor ?

Comment: At most 100 mA will flow into or out of the transceiver's bus pins. But it cannot do anything about the resistor being shorted to some external voltage.

Comment: Ref 8.3.3.6 from Datsheet -During CAN communication the bus switches between dominant and recessive states, therefore the short circuit current may be viewed either as the instantaneous current during each bus state or as an average current of the two states. For system current (power supply) and power considerations in
the termination resistors and common-mode choke ratings, use the average short circuit current - Could you please explain this ? They are asking to consider average short circuit current for sizing the resistor and choke

Comment: In the recessive state, a much smaller current can flow. So the average short-circuit current depends on how often your nodes send messages over the bus.